# How to get Oracle Wallet Manager for Windows 10

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-wallet

I want to install Oracle Wallet Manager for Windows 10 and for Oracle Database 11.2.

When I download the corresponding version of Oracle Client, I don't see the Oracle Wallet Manager OWM or orapki being part of the download (https://www.oracle.com/in/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html)

I don't have the database installed on my Windows machine.

My requirement is to connect to Oracle 11.2 database which is in cloud from a Java program running in Windows PC. I would like to connect to the database from credentials stored in Wallet. (Java program will not need to store database credentials).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wallet tools are on the full client and on the database server, not on the instant-client.

https://www.oracle.com/webapps/redirect/signon?nexturl=https://download.oracle.com/otn/nt/oracle19c/193000/WINDOWS.X64_193000_client_home.zip

Comment: I can see the orapki command as part of this but there is no oracle wallet manager. I installed this tool and tried running owm in command prompt. 

Is the oracle wallet manager separate tool that we need to install. Also my database is 11g and I did not find client home for 11. Is it downward compatible?

Comment: This tooling is merely a bunch of Java. It’s platform independent and backward compatible. The command line is your friend.